# Check if a Case Statement field is positive or negative Sql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have an sql query where i want to add another column,while checking if a case statement field has a positive value or not so to display the result as Sales or Refund. For example, i want to check if Total is a negative or positive value.If it is positive display Sales else display Refund

Example of Query below:

```
Select F01,
CASE 
WHEN R.F1034=3 THEN convert(DOUBLE PRECISION,  F65 * 100 ) * 10
ELSE 0 
END as Total
FROM RPT_CLT R
```

Comment: Edit your question and show what the results look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `XXX` with your field/calculation

```
SELECT CASE WHEN XXX >= 0 THEN 'Sales' ELSE 'Refund' END AS newfield
```

In your example:

```
SELECT F01,
CASE WHEN R.F1034 = 3 
     THEN CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION,  F65 * 100 ) * 10
     ELSE 0 
END AS Total,
CASE WHEN (CASE WHEN R.F1034 = 3 
     THEN CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION,  F65 * 100 ) * 10
     ELSE 0 
END) >= 0 THEN 'Sales' ELSE 'Refund' END AS newfield
FROM RPT_CLT R
```

Comment: Thanks, this small hack save time which I was working on it to fix some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select F01,
    CASE 
        WHEN R.F1034=3 THEN convert(DOUBLE PRECISION,  F65 * 100 ) * 10
        ELSE 0
    END as Total,
    CASE 
        WHEN (CASE WHEN R.F1034=3 
                   THEN convert(DOUBLE PRECISION,  F65 * 100 ) * 10
                   ELSE 0
              END)>=0 
        THEN 'Sales'
        ELSE 'Refund'
    END as Result
FROM RPT_CLT R
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select F01,
       Total,
       case when total>=0 then 'Sales' else 'Refund' end as new
from (
     select F01,
            case when R.F1034 = 3 
                 then convert(double precision,  F65*100)*10
                 else 0 
            end as Total
     from RPT_CLT
   )
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
Select F01,
       (CASE WHEN R.F1034 = 3
             THEN convert(DOUBLE PRECISION,  F65 * 100 ) * 10
             ELSE 0 
        END) as Total,
       (CASE WHEN R.F1034 = 3 AND F65 > 0 THEN 'SALES' ELSE 'REFUND'
        END) as which
FROM RPT_CLT R
```

It occurs to me that you might want `ABS()` so the `Total` is always positive.